# VIsual Studio editing feature.xml

Tags: 2010, development, visual-studio, feature, feature-stapling

I am trying to create a a feature staple. To do this I need to create a feature and then edit the feature.xml to be like:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation
        Id="edcdcd75-dff2-479d-ac32-b37f8fa9d459"
        TemplateName="STS#0" />
    <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation
        Id="edcdcd75-dff2-479d-ac32-b37f8fa9d459"
        TemplateName="STS#1" />
</Elements>
```

I have created a feature in Visaul Studio 2010. I however can't seem to find the feature.xml to edit. Where would I find this file in visual studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these lines (inside the Elements tag) to an 'Empty Element' project item, then add that Project Item to a Feature (Scoped to Web Application, for example) in the solution.